# ping of address fails

Tags: networking, command-line, dns, ping, netplan

Running on Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.1 shortly after an upgrade from 20.04 the command

ping 8.8.8.8

fails and reports 100% packet loss.

What tests would be diagnostic for the cause of this unexpected behavior?

In the larger context I am trying to restore internet access configuring and using Netplan (the NetworkManager GUI is also broken— the wired (Ethernet) option no longer pops up) from the CLI. This behavior of ping was discovered in testing for restored functionality (some progress but a disappointing result). A coincident failure of DNS to resolve names was discovered at the same time with failure response to the command

ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

I will respond with any tests and listings you wish me to share; but, I am hampered by the very lack of service that I am trying to repair (e.g., I may be reduced to sending screen shots via cellphone).

Thanks,

Craig Bourne

Answer (score 0):

`mtr` would show the detailed routes information and tell you which one failed.
For example `mtr 8.8.8.8`

In case the problem is from route, you may `route -n` to check the route configurations.